# Turning quota on yields warning message about device busy

Tags: filesystems, quota

I run `quotacheck` on a filesystem to enable user quota only so now the following file is present:

```
root@Cassiopeia:~# ls -l /mnt/imagemount/aquota.user 
-rw------- 1 root root 7168 Ιαν   8 15:21 /mnt/imagemount/aquota.user
```

(I have mounted a loopback device for the particular process)

However, when trying to enable quota:

```
root@Cassiopeia:~# quotaon -u /mnt/imagemount/
quotaon: using /mnt/imagemount/aquota.user on /dev/loop6 [/mnt/imagemount]: Device or resource busy
```

Why is it displaying the above message?

Do I need to make sure **no** process is accessing a particular filesystem before enabling quota? is there such a requirement?

Comment: what options did you mount the filesystem with? one I run quota on sets `usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0` for example

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the rights of `aquota.user` are `600` and try to type `remount /mnt/imagemount` before trying to type `quotaon`; if you do not remount after adding aquota.user, the system will not acknowledge the change.